# Batch File calling Java Issue

Tags: java, exception, batch-file, noclassdeffounderror

I currently have an open instance of the command prompt, it reads

```
java -cp .;jars/GUI.jar;jars/utils.jar;...(a bunch more jars in the same folder)... Test
```

where Test is my java program (class files already compiled).

When I hit enter, the program runs just fine. Now, I put the same exact line into a batch file for automatic runs but it gives me an error.

Batch File:

```
cd
java -cp .;jars/GUI.jar;jars/utils.jar;...(a bunch more jars in the same folder)... Test
pause
```

Error: Exception in Thread "Main" java.lang.NoClassDefFound Test (wrong name: Test)

I've been at this for hours today so at this point, this is the last thing I need to do, my brain is fried, am I missing something simple?

Comment: Does cd print out the directory you are expecting? Is the batch file in the same directory as Test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or the Bash script doesn't know where the PATH to the Java installation. I'd check the environment variables as well.

Comment: echo %cd% shows that it is in the current working directory (where the java files are present)

I added java to the path variable in the batch file, though that shouldn't be the problem because the command java by itself triggers java.exe just fine. I'm thinking it may be an issue with the java file itself, looking into it, Thanks for the inputs

Comment: I gave the full path name in quotes, no go. I'm just extremely confused at this point, I can run the program in an instance of the command prompt but when I attempt to replicate in a batch file (with the correct directories), it's a no go. As a side question, are there any special cases where the compiler cannot find/load the main class (excluding a missing main class as a cause)?

Comment: There can be issues when the jar never had the main class file to begin with or that the path leads to some other place. try invoking the actual java files with some javac and java commands. Lets remove the layer of the jar file for the next debug.

Comment: Got it, thanks. It was a missing class file in one of the jars.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try providing the full path of Test class: /x/y/Test
I'm not really sure of the exact rules but i guess the computer can't know which class you want to launch if Test.class is not in the current folder (current script folder? current cd/home folder?)